# Form validation with jquery not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using this plugin for form validation :

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

And I'm submitting form outside of the form, meaning I'm not directly clicking on the submit button inside the form being submitted. Here is what I mean(this is on some button click function) :

```
$('#myForm').attr('action', '/requested').attr('method', 'post').removeAttr('data-remote').submit();
```

I want to validate one field in this form, which I can see from firebug to be rendered like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="request" id="request" class="required">
```

And I try to call validation in document ready :

```
$('#myForm').validate();
```

But it doesn't work, I get no errors in firebug.

**Version II** :

HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" name="request" id="request">
```

Javascript :

```
$('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            request: "required"
        },
        messages : {
            request: "Request name can't be empty."
        }
    });
```

What is my next option both of these above don't work.

Comment: try to add $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); if you want to validate hidden fields

Comment: wow good catch, care to answer? I'll accept your answer

Comment: answer is below : ) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); if you want to validate hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

Just try using $('form').submit();

Hope it works.

If not $('form').submit(true);

Comment: I can't use `$('form').submit();` I have multiple forms on this page

Comment: Use it with the unique handler. Like $('form#id1').submit ();